# Como chamar o id do select anterior

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, json, django

Tenho 2 selects,um de divisão e o outro de grupos. Quando o de divisão for selecionado ele tem que trazer no segundo apenas os grupos que fazem parte daquela divisão. Na variável url que pega o json chamei o python de acordo com a minha view, mas no lugar desse 4 tem que ser o id do que foi selecionado anteriormente.
Nessa linha:var url = "{% url 'cadastro:all_json' 4 %}" ;

```
<script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {

        $("select#id_divisao").change(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $("select#id_grupos").html("<option>Selecione uma divisão</option>");
                $("select#id_grupos").attr('disabled', true);
            } else {
              var url = "{% url 'cadastro:all_json' 4 %}" ;
              $.getJSON(url, function(grupos) {

                    var options = '<option value="">Select uma divisão</option>';
                    for (var i = 0; i < grupos.length; i++) {
                        options += '<option value="' + grupos[i].pk + '">' + grupos[i].fields.grupo + '</option>';
                    }

                    $("select#id_grupos").html(options);
                    $("select#iid_grupos option:first").attr('selected', 'selected');
                });
            }
        });
   });
</script>
```

views.py:

```
def all_json_grupos(request, idDivisao):
    json_grupos = serializers.serialize("json",  Grupo.objects.filter(divisao_id=idDivisao))
    return HttpResponse(json_grupos)
```

Entro pela url e me mostra certinho os grupos de acordo com a divisão que coloquei, só preciso fazer funcionar no select

Comment: Consegue pegar o value do select anterior pelo name dele?

Comment: Estou pegando pelo id, porque na tabela de grupo eu tenho o id da divisão

Comment: Bom, você já conseguindo pegar esse id, o problema ( que vejo ) é como injetar ele na url do django.. Aqui está uma alternativa..

var url = "{% url 'urlpattern_name' {id} %}".replace('{id}', seu_id);

Com isso passe seu id pra string e depois pro getJSON.. Lembrando que o django tem uma classe pra serializer objetos django pra json..a JsonResponse

Comment: Obrigada Marlysson, consegui resolver adaptando o método que me mandou, desse modo: var url = "{% url 'cadastro:all_json' 4  %}".replace(4, $(this).val());

Comment: Opa, por nada. Vou só colocar a sugestão como resposta, para outras pessoas poderem se basear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, o seu problema como discutido nos comentários é como colocar o valor do `id` que você já está conseguindo capturar do html.

Pra isso você pode fazer um "hack" criando uma url do django em string simples no javascript , substituir o valor que você que e depois passar para alguma função do js para fazer as chamadas.. Ficaria assim:

```
....código anterior

var url = "{% url 'cadastro:all_json' id %}".replace('id', $(this).val())
$.getJSON(url, function(grupos) {
    ....continue seu código
}

....continuação do código
```